# SSRS summarized report

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, summarization

I am working on SSRS reporting and want to summarize (sum) the amount field and narrow the output of the report. As you can see on the below table, the data source has a **date** field which is unique for each row which make it difficult for me to summarize the output. I want the date field only for filtering purpose, I don't want to show the date data in the details of the report. But since the date field is there in the data which is returned by the query, and I am trying to filter the report using date field, I couldn't be able to summarize it (sum the amount field).

Any Idea?

current data set on SSRS returns the following result

```
id  item    date    amount
1   item 1  1/1/2015    1200
1   item 1  1/2/2015    1200
1   item 1  1/3/2015    1200
1   item 2  1/4/2015    100
1   item 2  1/5/2015    100
1   item 2  1/6/2015    100
```

My need (when I filter the report with: where date > = 1/1/2015 and date <= 1/6/2015)

```
id  Item    Amount
1   item 1  3600
1   item2   300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are summarizing the data in SSRS you just the group level not the detail section.

1. Create a Group by Item
2. Delete the detail section by clicking on the tablix.

[image]

3. Put the expression of the textbox `=SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)`
   [image]

The **other way** to handle this scenario is to **modify your query** and group by in query by the item while adding the Date filter in the where clause.